# Multiple independent random number streams from single seed

Tags: python, numpy, random, random-seed

I have `n` similar analyses each using `m_i` pseudo-random number streams (`m_i` may vary between analyses). Each analysis has its own random number seed so that the random numbers are uncorrelated between analyses.

My problem is that I need to create the `m_i` streams from the single seed. The analysis is currently written in Numpy, so solutions its Mersenne Twister are ideal, but I am open to solutions in other mature libraries. I considered these possibilities:

1. **Use the seed to create a random number stream, draw `m_i` integers, and use those integers as the seeds for `m_i` random streams.** This is not good because of the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). There are [2^32](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) (~4 billion) seeds, but if I would end up with a collision (two streams started with the same seed) after 2^16 (~60000).
2. **Multiply the seed by some constant `m_max` for each stream index by 1 to get that stream's seed.** (e.g. with `seed=2` and `m_max=10000`, the analysis will use seeds 20001, 20002, 20003, etc.). This is undesirable because all analyses will be limited to `m_max` streams before there will be collisions, and if `m_max` is too big, the number of analyses is limited to `2^32/m_max`.
3. **Use the seed to create a random number stream, draw [624](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) 32-bit [integers](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) per stream needed, and [set the state](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.set_state.html) of each stream to the 624 integers drawn for it.** This seems to be perfect except that I have no idea if 624 random integers is actually a valid internal state for the Mersenne Twister (can it be arbitrary bits?). I also don't know if there is any hidden correlation between the integers (maybe they are the same stream just shifted by 624).

Is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Approach 3 can work, as the seed for any PRNG can be as long as that PRNG's state (for example, Mersenne Twister has a state length of 19968 bits, or 624 * 32 bits, so can accept a seed of up to that many bits — it's not limited to 32 or 64 bits, as is the practice with many APIs that implement Mersenne Twister). However you should use a PRNG of an unrelated design to Mersenne Twister, such as PCG, to seed that PRNG, then draw the 624-integer seed as you suggest. (Or, if you don't require reproducible results or if you will save the 624-integer seeds generated this way, you can use a cryptographic RNG, such as `os.urandom()` or `secrets.SystemRandom`, to draw those seeds instead.) [My article on RNGs](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Examples_and_Non_Examples) suggests several PRNGs with different designs.

---

UPDATE (Dec. 1, 2019):

If you're using NumPy, please note that in the meantime, NumPy 1.17 introduces a [new random number generation system](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/index.html); it uses so-called *bit generators*, such as PCG, and *random generators*, such as the new `numpy.random.Generator`. It was the result of a [proposal to change the RNG policy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.rst). The NumPy documentation now has detailed information on [seeding RNGs in parallel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/parallel.html), and on [multithreading RNGs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/multithreading.html). I also have general information on seeding multiple processes (not NumPy-specific) in "[Seed Generation for Noncryptographic PRNGs](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Seed_Generation_for_Noncryptographic_PRNGs)."