# Impact of setting random.seed() to recreate a simulated behaviour and choosing the seed

Tags: python, random, random-seed

I am doing a scheduling simulation in python which is full determinstic. So, when I have the same input and parameters I always get the same output.

Now I want to randomize the initial starting state of the simulation and compare the output of two (or more) different simulation parameters. To compare the "same randomized initial starting state" I want to set the `random.seed()` with an initial value, which should stay the same for all comparisions of different schedulers. Furthermore I want to see the behaviour for one scheduler on different initial states so I have to change the `random.seed()`. This I have to do of course for all schedulers.

Now my question is, what impact has the seed on the "randomness" of the random generator? For example does it matter if I choose as a seed 1 or 100? And because I want to use different seeds for the same scheduler and compare it to the other ones, can I simply use e.g. the seeds 1 to 10 or must my seeds be "more random"?

For clarification, I use the random generator for distributing tasks initial on different cores and compare the output to "my optimal (deterministic) initial distribution". I want to get a wide-spread of different distributions with my choosen seeds.

Comment: If the PRNG is properly implemented, seed 1 should be as different from seed 2 as seed 100 would be from seed 1000000.

Comment: @deceze So you are saying it would be totally ok, to use the seeds 1 to 100 and then say I used randomly independent distributions? (I am writing my master thesis right now and I'm not that strong in statistics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your choice of seed shouldn't matter**

If the pseduo-random number generator is made correctly then any seed should create a random distribution of numbers.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed):

> For a seed to be used in a pseudorandom number generator, it does not need to be random. Because of the nature of number generating algorithms, so long as the original seed is ignored, the rest of the values that the algorithm generates will follow probability distribution in a pseudorandom manner.

Comment: Thanks! Also awesome that you shared a source for your answer!

Comment: @RoQuOTriX happy to help :)

Comment: This is only true in theory.  In practice this depends in part on the PRNG design, how big it is, and the range of seeds compared to the range of PRNG states.

Answer (score 3):

Although your choice of seed doesn't matter *in theory*, it may matter in practice.

1. There are many PRNGs for which a given seeding strategy will produce correlated pseudorandom number sequences. For example, in most versions of PCG, two sequences generated from seeds that differ only in their high bits [will be highly correlated](http://pcg.di.unimi.it/pcg.php) ("Subsequences from the same generator"). Another example, this time involving Unity's PRNG, is found in "[A Primer on Repeatable Random Numbers](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/01/07/a-primer-on-repeatable-random-numbers/)".
2. If you choose sequential seeds, or seeds that differ only very slightly, it may matter how the seed is used to initialize the PRNG's state. I don't know how well base Python's `random.seed(integer_seed)` avoids this problem, but if two Mersenne Twister states differ in only one bit, the two sequences they produce will be correlated to each other, and it will take [millions of numbers](http://pcg.di.unimi.it/pcg.php#flaws) to eliminate this correlation. A similar issue occurs with many other PRNGs, especially linear PRNGs.
3. Mersenne Twister has a huge state (about 20,000 bits) compared to other PRNGs in common use (which are typically 32 to 128 bits). Unless you seed a PRNG with a seed as big as its state, there will be some PRNG states that will never be produced (and therefore some pseudorandom number sequences that will never be generated). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53122853/multiple-independent-random-number-streams-from-single-seed), which discusses seeding Mersenne Twister, which is the algorithm used in base Python.

To reduce the risk of correlated pseudorandom numbers, you can use PRNG algorithms, such as SFC and other so-called "counter-based" PRNGs (Salmon et al., "Parallel Random Numbers: As Easy as 1, 2, 3", 2011), that support independent "streams" of pseudorandom numbers. (Note, however, that [PCG has a flawed notion of "streams"](http://pcg.di.unimi.it/pcg.php#flaws).) There are other strategies as well, and I explain more about this in "[Seeding Multiple Processes](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Seeding_Multiple_Processes)". See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58954557).

Also, if you're using NumPy (which is a popular Python library for scientific work), note that NumPy 1.17 introduces a [new pseudorandom number generation system](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/index.html); it uses so-called *bit generators*, such as PCG, and *random generators*, such as the new `numpy.random.Generator`. It was the result of a [proposal to change the PRNG policy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.rst). The NumPy documentation has detailed information on [seeding PRNGs in parallel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/parallel.html).